# Scale resolution and frequency resolution in continuous wavelet transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

I'm reading the well known wavelets tutorial by Robi Polikar [here](http://users.rowan.edu/~polikar/WAVELETS/WTpart3.html). In part 3, about figure 3.7 and 3.8, it says "lower scales (higher frequencies) have better scale resolution (narrower in scale, which means that it is less ambiguous what the exact value of the scale) which correspond to poorer frequency resolution". I don't understand why it is. From my opinion, scales are just reciprocal to the frequencies, but if scales are less ambiguous then so are frequencies. So I think good scale resolution also implies good frequency resolution. However, I know the conclusion is wrong. So how can I understand this statement.

Thanks

update:

I guess I still cannot convince myself by checking the following plot from the tutorial. The tutorial says it should have good frequency resolution and poor time resolution at low frequencies (high scale) and good time resolution and poor frequency resolution at high frequencies (low scale). From the plot, I can accept that high-frequency part has good time solution because it seems to have clear separation between different frequencies near scale 1. But which way should I understand that the low frequency has good frequency resolution? It seems to me that the low frequency part covers a quite large area and I cannot distinguish which frequencies it is actually

[image]

Comment: the more a filter is long in time the more it can have a good frequency resolution (extract only a small frequency band of the signal). reciprocally, the more a filter has a good frequency resolution, the longer it is in time (and the poorer its time resolution is). this is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle that you can prove by looking at the Fourier transform of $h(ax)$ which is $H(f/a)/a$ : the more concentrated in time is a signal, the less its Fourier transform will be concentrated in frequency.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I know time resolution and frequency resolution are reciprocal to each other due to the uncertain principle. I know this conclusion and I can accept it. What I don't understand is why the tutorial says "good scale resolution corresponds to poor frequency resolution". I think if a scale can be determined, the resolution is also fixed. This means, I think, if a scale is less ambiguous/more precise, frequency is also less ambiguous/more precise.

Comment: scale resolution is another word for time resolution... and we are talking of the time/frequency resolution of a single filter $h$ not of the wavelet family it can generate

Comment: @user1952009 Which way should I understand scale resolution as time resolution? I think translation parameter is related to time instead of scaling parameter, right?

Comment: for a fixed $s$, $CWT(s,\tau) = x \ast h(\tau)$ where $h = \varphi^*(-\tau/s)$. $\tau$ is the time position, $s$ is the time resolution : for a fixed $\tau$, $s$ tells us how much the values of $x(t)$ for $t$ far from $\tau$ are taken into account, or equivalently what is the maximal discretization step of $\tau$ which will let us reconstruct entirely $x \ast h(\tau)$ for every $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$ (the Shannon theorem)

Comment: @user1952009 I think I am a bit closer to what you mean. I need some time to think carefully. Really thanks for this discussion:-)

Comment: @user1952009 Hi, could you help by explaining the resolution issue based on the plot I added? I still cannot understand why it can be said that high-scale/low-frequency part provides good frequency resolution, because it seems that it is much harder than high-frequency to determine exactly what the frequency is due to wider support